# reactjs and firebase function db (database) not working on running

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

so this is my first project  with firebase and im trying to send data to database but the function is not working:

```
const onSignUp = async (email, password, username) => {
  try {
    const authUser = await createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
      firebase,
      email,
      password
    );
    db.collection("users").add({  
        owner_uid: authUser.user.uid,
        usernames: username,
        email: authUser.user.email,
        profile_pic: await randomProfiles()
      })
      .then(() => {
        console.log("CREATED");
        this.props.phase(0);
      })
      .catch(() => {
        console.log("ERROR");
        alert("Bruh");
      });
  } catch (error) {}
};
const randomProfiles = async () => {
  const respone = await fetch("https://randomuser.me/api");
  const data = await respone.json();
  return data.results[0].picture.large;
};
```

I think the problem might be in

```
db.collection("users").add({
```

THIS IS THE EDITED PART NEW CODE:

```
            // Import the functions you need from the SDKs you need
        import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
        import { getAuth } from "firebase/auth";
        import { getFirestore } from "firebase/firestore";
        // TODO: Add SDKs for Firebase products that you want to use
        // https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#available-libraries

        // Your web app's Firebase configuration
        const firebaseConfig = {
          apiKey: "AIzaSyDVy_vUuhZN-qwMmTOUjsViQ4gW36q-Xxk",
          authDomain: "social-media-app-d29f2.firebaseapp.com",
          projectId: "social-media-app-d29f2",
          storageBucket: "social-media-app-d29f2.appspot.com",
          messagingSenderId: "103854538000",
          appId: "1:103854538000:web:9c77e5a5f7de0c3cb7f995"
        };

        const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
        const auth = getAuth(app);
        const db = getFirestore(app);
        export { auth, db };
```

so this is my previous way of doing it

Comment: What is the problem here? The code looks fine at first look. Also you can use `await` for `add()` as well instead of using `then()` Also do you have any `onAuthStateChanged()` around that might be redirecting users somewhere else after sign up and before Firestore could add the doc?

Comment: "is not working" is really hard to help with. If you set a breakpoint on each line, run in the debugger, and then check the value of each variable on each line, what is the first line that doesn't do what you expect it to do?

Comment: it dosent update the database at all and i didnt use onAuthstatechanged at all . and the .then function is not working cause its supposed to change the page to homescreen but it dosent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are mixing Firebase SDKs V8 and V9 syntax.

`const authUser = await createUserWithEmailAndPassword(...)` is V9 syntax

while

`db.collection("users").add(...)` is V8 syntax.

---

Adapting your code as follows should do the trick. I don't know how you defined the `firebase` Object you pass to the `createUserWithEmailAndPassword()` method, so I included all the imports and initialization code. It's up to you to adapt this part.

```
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";

import { getAuth, createUserWithEmailAndPassword } from "firebase/auth";
import { getDatabase, collection, addDoc } from "firebase/firestore";

const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

const onSignUp = async (email, password, username) => {
    try {
        const auth = getAuth(app);

        const authUser = await createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
            auth,
            email,
            password
        );
               
        const db = getDatabase(app);
            
        await addDoc(collection(db, "users"), {
            owner_uid: authUser.user.uid,
            usernames: username,
            email: authUser.user.email,
            profile_pic: await randomProfiles()
        });

        this.props.phase(0);

    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
};
```

Comment: so it almost worked but even though i have firestore dependency installed, it gives me error saying this:
`const db = getDatabase(app);`
is not a function
i have updated the question with firebase code please check

Comment: Are you sure you import `db` in the other file?